# knockout loading problems in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint, knockout.js, reload

I'm working on a knockoutjs project. It's sharepoint-hosted and in chrome every thing works fine. 
So I tried to open the site in Internet explorer and it looks like every thing is okay but if I try to reload, it loads a empty page just the footer is shown.
I think it looks like the components won't load but the console gives no errors.

I realy hope someone can help...
thanks 
Sophia

Comment: How can we possibly help? You've given nothing for us to work with at all. No code, no pictures, no error messages. Take a look at your post. If you were me, would you be able to help you?

Comment: Going out on a limb, have you tried using `data-bind="component: blah"` instead of custom elements? [See Here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#note-custom-elements-and-internet-explorer-6-to-8)

Comment: @JohnPavek Could be right. Using of custom elements could the reason of failure in old IE. Here more info about components and IE - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#note-custom-elements-and-internet-explorer-6-to-8

Comment: Thank you all for your effort. Unfortunately it still dosn't work... but I will keep trying :)

Comment: @gforce301 I'm sorry, but it hasn't any error messages and I realy don't know which part of the code you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the mistake :) 
My fault was, that I had the script tags in the header

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>Knockout-project</title>
<meta name="description" content="Start-Seite" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png">
<!-- build:css -->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:js -->
<script src="app/require.config.js"></script>
<script data-main="app/startup" src="../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild --></head>
```

But they have to be after the footer-tag...

```
<footer></footer>

<!-- build:js -->
<script src="app/require.config.js"></script>
<script data-main="app/startup" src="../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild --></body>
```